# Infinite loop when querying cart items from aws dataStore using react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I am fetching data from AWS DataStore and there is an infinite loop when fetching the cart item data from the DataStore. I don't know where this loop came from. I tried to wrap fetchCartItems function with useCallback, also removed the dependencies from the useEffect hook but nothing changed. I get this infinite loop when I console log the cartProducts.

This is the cart item context

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useContext,
  createContext,
  useCallback,
} from "react";
import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";
import { CartItems } from "../src/models";
import { useAuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

const CartContext = createContext({});

const CartContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([]);
  const { authUser } = useAuthContext();
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  // console.log(cartProducts)
  const addToCart = async (item) => {
    try {
      const foundCartItem = await DataStore.query(CartItems, (i) =>
        i.productId("eq", item.id)
      );

      if (foundCartItem.length === 0) {
        await DataStore.save(
          new CartItems({
            userId: authUser.attributes.sub,
            productId: item.id,
            productPrice: item.price,
            productTitle: item.title,
            productImage: item.image,
            quantity: quantity,
          })
        );
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error is: ", error);
    }
  };
  const fetchCartItems = async () => {
    try {
      const cartData = await DataStore.query(CartItems, (user) =>
        user.userId("eq", authUser.attributes.sub)
      );
      setCartProducts(cartData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  };

    const onRemove = async(deleteProduct)=>{
    const original = await DataStore.query(CartItems, deleteProduct)
    if(original.quantity > 1){
        await DataStore.save(CartItems.copyOf(original, updated=>{
            updated.quantity -=  1}))
    } else{
        const deletedItem = await DataStore.query(CartItems, deleteProduct)
        await DataStore.delete(deletedItem);
    }
}

    const clearCart = async ()=>{
    let cartItemsArr = [];
    for(let i in cartProducts){
        cartItemsArr.push(cartProducts[i])
        const deleteItemData = await DataStore.query(CartItems, cartItemsArr[i].id)
        await DataStore.delete(deleteItemData);
    }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCartItems();
  }),
    [addToCart, quantity, ];

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cartProducts,
        setCartProducts,
        addToCart,
        quantity,
        setQuantity,
        onRemove,
       clearCart
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default CartContextProvider;
export const useCartContext = () => useContext(CartContext);
```

This is the cart item screen

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import ItemQuantity from "../../component/ItemQuantity";
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import { useCartContext } from "../../contexts/CartContext";
const CartItem = () => {
 const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { cartProducts, onRemove} = useCartContext();
    const { createNewOrder } = useOrderContext();

const cartItems=[];

   for(const key in cartProducts){
    cartItems.push(cartProducts[key])
   }

   let totalPrice = 0;
   for(const i in cartItems){
    totalPrice += cartItems[i].productPrice * cartItems[i].quantity;
  }


   return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.totalAmount}>
          <Text style={styles.totalText}>الإجمالي:{'  '}<Text style={styles.subtotal}>
                    {totalPrice.toFixed(2)} ج.م </Text></Text>
              <Button 
                onPress={()=>{createNewOrder(totalPrice), navigation.navigate("OrderItems")}}
                  disabled={cartItems.length === 0} 
                  color={Colors.accent} title="اطلب"/>
          </View>
          <FlatList data={cartItems} renderItem={({item})=>{
              return(
                  <Cart_Item 
                      quantity={item.quantity} 
                      title={item.productTitle} 
                      amount={item.productPrice} 
                      deletable
                      onRemove={()=>{onRemove(item.id)}}
                      />
              )
          }}/>
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    margin: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: Why addToCart and quantity are dependencies of your useEffect ? They are not even used

Comment: when i remove them i don't get a real-time update i mean i have to reload the app to see the changes in cart items if i delete or increase quantity i need to reload the app to get the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you put your `useEffect`'s dependencies after initialising the hook.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetchCartItems();
  }),
    [addToCart, quantity];
```

`fetchCartItems` is being called with every render, because the hook has no dependencies (not even an empty array making it be called once), and on every call it edits the state, rerendering the dom and calling itself again.

`addToCart` shouldn't be in your `useEffect`'s dependencies, as it as function that you don't ever change in your code. Try:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchCartItems();
}, [quantity]);
```

Comment: thank you for your response. it actually stopped the infinite loop but another issue occurred. when i delete an item from the cart, it doesn;t get deleted instantly, but i have to reload the app to delete this item.

Comment: Well, I'm not even sure how your "addToCart" method works. You add the item to your DataStore, but you don't update the `cartProducts` state. If I understand correctly, that's the array that gets mapped to actual items on screen. In that case, what I believe you need to do then is just update the `cartProducts` whenever you add or remove items.